# Add an child image on a parent image at exact location , even if i will increase/decrease the parent image size using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

Step 1:
I have an image with size 400x300. Now, I am clicking on the image and I find the click position (top,left) and mark that location by an small image icon and save this information into database (top and left).

Step 2:
Now I have the same image but with size (700*500). Now, I want to show that clicked position that I stored in the database during Step 1 with an small image icon on this image.

Problem:
The problem is that the in the case of image with size 400*300 the appearance position is correct , but in case of image with size 700*500 we are getting problem to place the icon at clicked position. In both case the value of (top,left) of small icon is equal.

This whole process I want to do via jQuery. Please suggest

Comment: try using jQuery .height() and .width() function to get current eliment position relative to the value stored in database.  http://api.jquery.com/width/   http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Could you share some of the logic behind this code? Seems like the problem isn't necessary in calculating where the image should go, but in the final placement of the marker.

Seems like you could use a wrapper around the clicked IMG. Get the click position based on this wrapper (% left, % top, etc). Then in the larger size, place the marker using these % values

Comment: Actually the logic that is that suppose i have my friend group image in which i just mark a friend image by an UI element and save the click position(top,left) in database and at the next steps i am getting the same image but with big size then i want to show the mark friend with the an UI element, for that i am fetching the saved info (top,left) from database and showing the UI element but the appearance of UI element is different in both image due to only size of images, so i want to show UI element at same position in both image.this i am doing whole things by using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be used to implement ckaufman's recommendation.

```
image1.click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        width = $(this).width(),
        height = $(this).height(),
        leftPercent = (e.clientX - offset.left)/width,
        topPercent = (e.clientY - offset.top)/height;

    // position marker image appropriately and 
    // store leftPercent and topPercent in database
});
```

Then to set the position of the marker on a differently sized version of the same image you could do something like:

```
var leftPercent = .45, // from database
    toppercent = .23

image2.load(function() {
    var width = $(this).width(),
        height = $(this).height(),
        leftPosition = Math.round(leftPercent*width),
        topPosition = Math.round(topPercent*height);

    // set the marker position to leftPosition and topPosition
    // note: this is relative to the top left of the main image
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please See My Code

Getting the click position at the time of Marking means click event of image1

```
      var PosX = 0;
                    var PosY = 0;
                    var ImgPos;
      //here i am getting the exact position of image with size (400*300)
                    ImgPos = FindPosition(sender);
                    if (!e) var e = window.event;
                    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                        PosX = e.pageX;
                        PosY = e.pageY;
                    }
                    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
                        PosX = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                        PosY = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                    }
     //these two value i am saving in database
                    PosX = PosX - ImgPos[0];
                    PosY = PosY - ImgPos[1];
      //gettting the position of image 
                    function FindPosition(oElement) {
                    if (typeof (oElement.offsetParent) != "undefined") {
                        for (var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
                            posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
                            posY += oElement.offsetTop;
                        }                                                  
                        return [posX, posY];

                    }
                    else {
                        return [oElement.x, oElement.y];
                    }
                }
```